# Error during creation of new mail system for MailPlus on Synology

Tags: mail-server

I'm trying to install MailPlus Server on my Synology NAS but constantly get an error during setup. I can't find anything in logs etc. so it's a blackbox failing. In earlier tries it mentioned something about ports being in use by another application but after disabling the port 25 in the settings for MailPlus I get the not conclusive error message below.

Here's my setup procedure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The message says: The operation failed. Sign into to your DSM and try again.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days of trying to get MailServer up and running on my Synology I decided to give MailPlus another try. Uninstalled MailServer and installed MailPlus again. And look all the work I had done on MX and A records payed off. It seems that MailPlus needs a correctly set up MX configuration. It would have been nice if the error not just said 'services x (failed)' but a more detailed message. Now MailPlus is up and running and looking fine.